# How can I handle invitationId from the notification is status bar

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

How can I manage the invitation from the status bar?
I explain: 
if I override the onInivitationListener, I can get the information from the bundle, but when I don't run the app, and the invitation comes from the status bar autamatically, so I don't have an onActivityResult where I can get the bundle.

I can't use getInvitationId comes from BaseGameActivity, becouse it doesn't works.

Any ideas?

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

You get your invitation ID in the **onConnect(Bundle connectionHint)** Method from the GameHelper which implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks.

Comment: SO: You get the Invitation Id in the onSignInSucceeded() method from the ConnectionCallbacks with gameHelper.getInvitation() / gameHelper.getInvitationId()

Answer (score 0):

If you are deriving from **BaseGameActivity**, then you must call getInvitationId() only after sign-in succeeds. For example, call it from **onSignInSucceeded**.

From our ButtonClicker sample:

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Sign-in succeeded.");

    // install invitation listener so we get notified if we receive an
    // invitation to play
    // a game.
    getGamesClient().registerInvitationListener(this);

    // if we received an invite via notification, accept it; otherwise, go
    // to main screen
    if (getInvitationId() != null) {
        acceptInviteToRoom(getInvitationId());
        return;
    }
    switchToMainScreen();
}
```

Comment: getInvitationId returns null on Android v2.3